# Crossfading - Best way of getting audio C# .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, audio

I'm using .NET Compact Framework 3.5 and I'm wanting to crossfade two tracks of music.

The time at which they would crossfade isn't known, the idea is one would loop and something would trigger a crossfade.

I know SoundPlayer can play multiple tracks on top of one another and that (though I've not been able to get it to work), WaveOut is able to control volume (maybe fade?!).

Is there any way of incorporating these functionalites?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the audio capabilities built into .NET CF are quite limited.  for serious audio capabilities, you'll need to use a separate library - FMOD is popular for this.

Answer (score 0):

.Net CF runs on multiple type of devices with different capabilites. Depending on the specific features of your target device, you might be able to use Windows Media Player activex control. OpenNetCF team has a commercial component allowing to use this activex control from .Net CF.